# What's wrong with my loop/timer?

Tags: vb.net

This program is designed to listen for a pre-determined keypress, once pushed it no longer listens and the count down from a pre-determined number begins and at the end it plays a sound, then begin listening again.

The problem I am having, is that if the pre-determined key is E, if I press E twice within the countdown period, it will go through the loop twice and play the sound twice after each countdown.

I want the program to listen for a key at the beginning and after the sound only, not inbetween.

This is the code:

```
Private Sub DotTimer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DotTimer1.Tick
    Dim lngLoopCntr1 As Integer
    Dim lngMilliSecs1 As Integer

    If (GetAsyncKeyState(keyCodeKeyboard1)) And loopD1 = 0 And Not My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown Or (GetAsyncKeyState(keyCodeKeyboard1)) And loopD1 = 0 And My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown And ShiftTime.SelectedItem = "Yes" Then 'keyCodeKeyboard1 is a text input from form

        loopD1 = 1
        DotTimer1.Stop() 'stop's getasynckeystate from polling whilst loop process
        lngLoopCntr1 = 0

        lngMilliSecs1 = 1000 * dotTimeNum1 - 10

        Do While True 'loop countdown
            Sleep(10)
            lngLoopCntr1 = lngLoopCntr1 + 10
            If lngLoopCntr1 > lngMilliSecs1 Then Exit Do

        Loop


        If lngLoopCntr1 > lngMilliSecs1 And loopD1 = 1 Then 'plays tone once countdown finished
            My.Computer.Audio.PlaySystemSound( _
System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep)


        End If
    End If
    loopD1 = 0
    DotTimer1.Start() 'restarts timer
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: What is `DotTimer1` and why do you think that it has any effect on `GetAsyncKeyState`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure that what you want to do is *not* to try to turn `GetAsyncKeyState` off, but rather just call it at the end of your `Tick` event-handler and discard the results.  This way, anything pressed during that time cannot be picked up by a later call to `GetAsyncKeyState`, including the next time the event-handler is called.

```
Dim dummy As Integer
dummy = GetAsyncKeyState(keyCodeKeyboard1)
' Do nothing. Just ignore the results...
```